# django 1.9 AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am getting the following error when using ListView in django 1.9

```
File "/Users/jeffrey.dambly/hyperion/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 201, in get_template_names
    # If the list is a queryset, we'll invent a template name based on the
    # app and model name. This name gets put at the end of the template
    # name list so that user-supplied names override the automatically-
    # generated ones.
    if hasattr(self.object_list, 'model'):
        opts = self.object_list.model._meta
        names.append("%s/%s%s.html" % (opts.app_label, opts.model_name, self.template_name_suffix))

    return names


AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

here is the view

```
class DeviceView(ListView):
     model = LbDevice
     template_name = 'loadbalancer/device.html'
     context_object_name = 'device'

    def get_queryset(self):
         return self.model.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

for some reason my mode doesn't seem to have ._meta and I do not understand why, here is what my model looks like

```
class LbDevice(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    model = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=None, null=True)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=None, null=True)
    host_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=None, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=None, null=True)
    chassis_serial = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=None, null=True)
    uptime = timedelta.fields.TimedeltaField(default=None, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

   class Meta:
       ordering = ['label']

   def __unicode__(self):
       return "%s" % self.label
```

if I over rode get_tempalte_names with my own method the view works ( it's just a copy pasta of the method from TemplateResponseMixin). it seems like when the method from MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin is used this causes a problem.

also using runserver_plus I see the following, object_list does have the ._meta attribute, but if I add .model._meta I get the error

```
[console ready]
>>> self.object_list
<LbDevice: LbDevice object>
>>> self.object_list._meta
<Options for LbDevice>
>>>
```

Comment: after looking at this more it seems that  opts = self.object_list.model._meta, should be  opts = self.object_list._meta, is this a bug?

Comment: No, because `self.object_list` is a queryset and doesn't have a _meta attribute. You've somehow overwritten that attribute with a string. You need to show the code, as Ludwik asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_queryset` method should return a **queryset**. You are using `get()`, which returns a single instance.

If you only want to display a single item, then, `DetailView` would be more suitable than `ListView`.

Comment: I switched to detailed view and now it's working, thanks for the help